# Is this query possible using Criteria or DetachedCriteria Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, detachedcriteria

The question is simple can this query be done in Hibernate using Criteria or DetachedCriteria? i guess not but i wanted to do this question maybe exist a workaround.

```
SELECT
  COLUMNS 
FROM table
WHERE id not in (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT id 
        FROM table
        WHERE
        SOMECONDITIONS   
        ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 0, 15
  ) 
  as t);
```

I will mark the answer by @Dean Clark as correct but another question arises is the following

```
where can i find the findByCriteria from SessionFactory we are not using Spring
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To exactly match you query, you really need to do it with 2 steps, but I'd avoid this if possible:

```
final Criteria innerCriteria = getSession().createCriteria(YourEntity.class);
// SOME CONDITIONS
innerCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("someColumn", "someValue"));
innerCriteria.addOrder(Order.desc("timestamp"));
innerCriteria.setMaxResults(15);
innerCriteria.setProjection(Projections.id());
List<YourIdClass> ids = innerCriteria.list();


final Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(YourEntity.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.in("id", ids)));
List<YourEntity> results = criteria.list();
```

Would the objects you're trying to identify have the same "SOMECONDITIONS"? If so, this would functionally accomplish what you're looking for:

```
final DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(YourEntity.class);
// SOME CONDITIONS
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("someColumn", "someValue"));
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("timestamp"));
getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria, 16, 9999999);
```

Comment: where can i find the findByCriteria from SessionFactory we are not using Spring